# Rebasing with Squashing during Open Pull Request

Tags: git, git-workflow

## BEAR WITH ME IT IS LONG

### Introduction

There is a open pull request from branch `working-branch` into `development` branch which is one of the main branches with following commits:

```
Commit 1
Commit 2
Commit 3
```

### Code Review

Now another developers picks this pull request and code reviews then he request changes to the `Commit 1` and `Commit 3` per example.

### Approach 1

Developer creates `Commit 4` where all feedback is implemented and pushes it to the repo which in turn will appear on pull request commits history.

**Downsides** given more and more feedback might apply to the pull request then commits on the actual PR will look like

```
Commit 1
Commit 2
Commit 3
Commit 4 (first round of feedback)
...
Commit n
```

### Approach 2

Developer creates locally new commits e.g. `Commit 4` to action requested changes and `Commit 5` to action changes for `Commit 3` (alternatively commit 5 might not even exist as he actions first request changes for commit 3 and then simply amends them)

#### New structure(locally) looks like following

```
Commit 1
Commit 2
Commit 3
Commit 4 -> contains updates from PR for Commit 1
Commit 5 -> Contains updates from PR for Commit 3
```

Then developer does following `git rebase HEAD~5 -i` which outputs following

```
pick 1111111 Commit 1
pick 2222222 Commit 2
pick 3333333 Commit 3
pick 4444444 Commit 4
pick 5555555 Commit 5
```

and squashes `Commit 4` and `Commit 5`

```
pick 1111111 Commit 1
f 4444444 Commit 4
pick 2222222 Commit 2
pick 3333333 Commit 3
f 5555555 Commit 5
```

Which after rebasing will have 3 commits as per initial intention.

**Downsides**

In case another developer branched off your branch then after this he/she needs to rebase off your branch(it is not a downside if developer know how to do this kind of rebasing) as commit hashes change.

**Pros**

Better transparency of history, where and what has been implemented.
More compact history (without having additional commits with small changes)

### Question

What approach have you been practising, do you have different opinion about above? 
In your opinion which one of the above is better to pick up?
Do you know of any outside links (official/non-official documentation) which tells to use one approach or another.

### Conclusion

I personally (and our internal team) work with Approach 2.